# What American military strategist is Yves de Gaulle referring to?

Tags: united-states, military

In this [visit of Charles de Gaulle's personal library](https://youtu.be/wOKXTvlVcvg?si=hW65RMgPRMIvIlqU&t=1575), his grandson Yves de Gaulle mentions his was surprised not to have found books from US military strategists, including "Maran"(?). Who is he referring to?

"Où sont les grands classiques militaires comme Maran(?), l'américain".

(Where are the great military classics such as Maran(?), the American."

Comment: Could it be [A. T. Mahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Thayer_Mahan)  - single letter difference.

Comment: @MCW that's probably it! Please write it as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @MCW: seems the right person, I was typing while you posted, no correlation

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Listening carefully, he's talking about [Alfred Thayer Mahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Thayer_Mahan) (and not "Maran", but the recording isn't *that* good, had to listen to it several times to make sure it was the right person):

> Alfred Thayer Mahan (/məˈhæn/; September 27, 1840 – December 1, 1914) was a United States naval officer and historian, whom John Keegan called "**the most important American strategist of the nineteenth century.**"

About his work [here](https://history.state.gov/milestones/1866-1898/mahan):

> In 1890, Captain Alfred Thayer Mahan, a lecturer in naval history and the president of the United States Naval War College, published The Influence of Sea Power upon History, 1660–1783, a revolutionary analysis of the importance of naval power as a factor in the rise of the British Empire. Two years later, he completed a supplementary volume, The Influence of Sea Power upon the French Revolution and Empire, 1793–1812.

Comment: Not used to hearing French people pronounce "h" which is silent in French, ended up hearing it as an "R".

Comment: did the same to me, especially when people try and mimic the so-called native accent.